# How to know variable name adhering to go error

Tags: go, design-patterns, error-handling

When working with go there is a pattern used to define errors and handle them in a (to me) very peculiar way. Often errors are declared like `ErrorSomethingWentWrong = errors.New("Just an example!")`. You can use `errors.Is(err, ErrorSomethingWentWrong)` to catch that specific error. The `Is` function can do this by comparing the pointers. But in order to make the comparison I need to know which variable name is used to define the `errorString` so I can use `errors.Is` to catch it.

For example:

```
ErrorSomethingWentWrong = errors.New("Just an example!")
func DoSomething() (*Something, error) {
    return nil, ErrorSomethingWentWrong
}
```

I know a error is returned with the string `"Just an example!"` But I don't know it has the variable name `ErrorSomethingWentWrong`:

```
func checkError() {
    if errors.Is(err, ErrorSomethingWentWrong){ // how to know this???
       //handle error
    }
}
```

When I use `errors.Is(err, ErrorSomethingWentWrong)` I can catch this error and handle it. When using debugging I can't see that the `errorString` represents the `ErrorSomethingWentWrong` variable. But when I don't know that the variable name was `ErrorSomethingWentWrong` I need to reverse engineer the code or read the docs to know which error is returned.

[image]

So how can you know using debugging or reflection to retrieve the error variable name?

Comment: A Go value and the variable's name it may be stored in has no connection. Given a value, you can't tell what variables store that value, there may be multiple, one or none at all. The value of `db.ErrorNotFound` may be stored in a variable named `db.ErrorFound`. Again, no connection. Consult the documentation of the API or package you're using, the docs should cover these.

Comment: @icza I agree and Understand. But then how can `errors.Is()` discriminate beween errors based on the variable name? And how am I supposed to sniff this variable name when there is no documentation and the used library is a black box.

Comment: `errors.Is()` is a function, Go _values_ are passed to it, not variable names. `errors.Is(err, db.ErrorNotFound)` receives 2 values, the value stored in the `err` and `db.ErrorNotFound` variables. `errors.Is()` operates on values, not variable names. `errors.Is()` checks whether the value stored in `err` is or wraps the value stored 
in the `db.ErrorNotFound` variable.

Comment: @icza Thanks for your answer, you are right ofc it is comparing values. But how is this https://go.dev/play/p/WjFsCaKdHJG possible then? Two errors with exact same value, still it discriminates. Is it maybe comparing if the pointers are equal? Which is brilliant. But now I still need the variable name to point to the pointer. (sorry I'm not a C programmer the concept of pointers is new for me)

Comment: Yes, `errors.New()` deliberately creates new, distinct error values even if the same text is used. And it does so by using pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is your scenario:

You are receiving an error from a package, and there is no documentation to provide you with the errors you should be handling. You are debugging, and see an `errors.errorString`, but don't know if there is a global and public error value that you can compare to.

Unfortunately, this is a value and the debugger can't tell you if this is a global variable or if so which one, because you don't receive a variable, only a value.

You can:

- read through the source code of the package you are calling and see which errors are being returned and how to handle them
- search the source code for the text in the error string, this could help you pinpoint where the error is defined or created.

If it turns out the specific error you wish to handle is not defined globally (and re-writing the package is not feasible for your case), so you can't handle it. This can happen if somebody uses `errors.New` inside a function (bad practice). Then you can also try these:

```golang
func handleError(err error) {
    if err.Error() == "full error string" {}

    if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "partial error string") {}
}
```

But those are both ugly imho.

**TL;DR** It's not possible, you have to read the source code.

Comment: I accept your answer, it simply is not possible to trace which variable defined the error string. It simply is a matter of reading docs and reverse engineer (search for error string in source) code to find it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that an error may not be a variable at all, just value. For example, one can do:

```
func foo() error {
    ...
    if somethingWrong {
        return fmt.Errorf("some error")
    }
    ...
```

In this case, `fmt.Errorf()` is a function that returns an error that's not stored in any variable. So looking at the package source code in this case doesn't help, as there's no variable to be found.

Another thing is the error variables might be private (i.e. start with lowercase), so even if you find an error variable in the package source code, you can't use it in your own code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).